# Yii2 App not displaying on Heroku domain

Tags: php, heroku, yii, yii2

I installed a Yii2 "basic" app on a Cloud9 workspace using composer. It runs fine as you can see here https://portfolio-php--dfmmalaw.c9.io/basic/web/index.php

Problem is I am getting below error when trying to view after deploying to Heroku URL.

"Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server."

The below screenshot is my Cloud9 workspace 
http://prntscr.com/8rrkn0

I even tried adding basic/web/index.php to the Heroku URL but I just get a blank page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After getting help from Herokai, David Zuelke, I decided to create a how-to on the subject of "Creating Yii2 App in Cloud9 → Pushing to Github → Deploying to Heroku". Please see below (google doc link at top if easier to read):

https://docs.google.com/document/d/15teHaGWUWSNW_VwdV3-7bVpQHNRv2G0Z8GPFbIB-ogs/edit

1) Create Yii2 “basic” app:

```
290795 $ composer create-project --prefer-dist yiisoft/yii2-app-basic basic
```

2) Move into “basic” directory

```
290795 $ cd basic/
```

3) Initialize local repo for “basic” directory

```
basic $ git init
```

4) Add and commit Yii project

```
basic $ git add .
basic $ git commit -m "basic Yii project"
```

5) Add procfile that will point to index.php (entry script) in “web” directory

```
basic $ echo "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 web/" > Procfile
basic $ git add Procfile 
basic $ git commit -m "Procfile for Heroku"
```

6) Comment out debugging stuff (I do this manually instead of from command line)

```
basic $ vim web/index.php # remove dev/debug env stuff (not my way)
basic $ git add web/index.php 
basic $ git commit -m "remove dev/debug env"
```

7) This updates the dependency from v1.0.3 to v1.1 (absolute necessity)

```
basic $ composer require fxp/composer-asset-plugin
basic $ git add composer.json composer.lock 
basic $ git commit -m "use fxp/composer-asset-plugin in project"
```

8) Create Heroku app and push to it. (I instead create and push to Github repo)

```
basic $ heroku create
basic $ git push heroku master (again I push to Github Repo synced with Heroku)
```

9) Add logging to Heroku for Yii app (no logging for Yii out of the box)

```
basic $ echo "web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 -l runtime/logs/app.log web/" > Procfile
basic $ git add Procfile 
basic $ git commit -m "tail runtime/logs/app.log"
basic $ git push heroku master (again I push to Github Repo synced with Heroku)
```

10) This allows the “Contact” page to work (not sure why)

```
basic $ composer require ext-gd:* --ignore-platform-reqs
basic $ git add composer.json composer.lock 
basic $ git commit -m "require GD for contact CAPTCHA"
basic $ git push heroku master (again I push to Github Repo synced with Heroku)
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way is to check your apache logs. I do not have experience with Heroku but I am sure they do offer access to them. Just take a look in there and you will see what the problem is. A white page usually means that is was a catastrophic error.

Another thing to look at is if you have used short php tags. You should not and that usually is a setting more relaxed on your computer but more strict on hosting servers. But again look at the logs, they will tell you this too.

This is for the advanced template so not for you: 
I guess you did not run 'php init' like the documentation tells you. The init command is not just for the first time you get the application, but for every time you set it up on a new server too. it creates index.php and other config files that you will need for sure. Just follow again the yii2 install instructions
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-start-installation.html

Comment: Hello Mihai. I do not see where it says to use the "php init" command in the documentation you linked above. The index.php file was created when I installed the Yii2 framework via Composer. It is located in the basic/web directory and I am able to run the application in Cloud9 as you can see here >>>>>> http://prntscr.com/8rtpbq

Comment: hello, sorry I worked too much on the advanced template, that one has an init. Let me figure out what is what.